# Impala shell or Spark for ETL?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, etl, impala

I have recently started working on Hadoop environment. I needed to do some basic ETL to populate few tables. Currently I am importing data into Hadoop using sqoop and using Impala shell command to write SQL queries for transformations.

But I am hearing about Spark a lot these days. In my situation will I have any advantage writing my ETL in Spark instead of Impala shell?

Thanks
S

Comment: Bad choice in my view. Impala is used.

Comment: SQL has apart from select also insert, update, delete. For eons people have been writing ETL using SQL. Hence Impala, ImpalaQL have also been used in a similar vein to do ETL. The notion of the other answer being better than mine, is less obvious. You cannot select 2 answers by the way. I am curious to an explanation.

Comment: @thebluephantom as you can tell I am new to stackoverflow. If I am doing something wrong when accepting answers please let me know. I am not too familiar with what happens when I accept.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people in the past were using either A) SQL Scripts (like Impala) with UNIX scripts or using B) ETL tools for ETL.

However, the question is 1) more of scale imo and 2) standardizing on technologies.

Since Spark is being used, then why not standardize on Spark?

I have been thru this cycle and Kimball DWH processing can be done quite OK with Spark. It means less costs in terms of paid ETL tools like Informatica. But there are community editions.

Some points to note:

- Saving of file to different HDFS formats is easier and more direct with Data Frame Writer etc.
- But Informatica-like mappings with branches are a little different.
- Performance at scale will be better with Spark once data gotten form external sources.
- File control is easier with UNIX scripting than inside Spark imo, but it is a case of getting used to if done within Spark.
- Sqoop can be obviated and you can use JDBC DF Reader of Spark, but there is no reason to dispense with sqoop, although I would use Confluent Kafka Connect instead with higher latency, but then we get into Zen Questions as Kafka is for more real-time aspects.
- I am not convinced overall of the benefits of ETL tools.

With cost reductions that IT needs to under go, Spark is a good option. But it is not for the faint-hearted, you need to be a good programmer. That is what I hear many people saying.

Comment: Thanks thebluephantom for your response. 

We are following the same method  you mentioned. 
ETL tools for our data warehouse
impala and shell scripts for data loading/transformations in Hadoop

We do not want to buy ETL tools for Hadoop work. We want to continue to use tools already available in Hadoop ecosystems. 

Now one point you mentioned on standardizing. Using Spark instead of Imapala/shell scripts is only advantageous for standardizing or will there be real performance gain? I did not understand that point from your reponse.

Comment: Impala is by definition fast compared to HiveQL using Map Reduce. Spark is really for big volumes, there is an overhead in starting a Spark job. But a standard approach has appeal and people of course want to learn something new for their CV. Fine with the latter. Spark is not suitable for all kpi processing though.

Comment: By touching clicking on the tick

Comment: I just accepted it. It took a while to understand how to accept it as this is first time posting something on stackoverflow. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that Impala is not an ETL tool, it's a SQL query engine that allows you to do SQL queries on very large data sets after data has been cleaned through the ETL process.

Historically Pig and Hive were used for ETL prior to Spark.  Hive is still relevant if you prefer SQL like syntax and there are many variants that offer better performance like Hive on Tez and Hive on Spark which replaces MapReduce with Spark.

**References**

- [Hive on Spark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started)
- [Hive on Tez](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Tez)

Comment: You can use the +1 instead of marking the accept (checkbox) as @thebluephantom's answer is more comprehensive.  I'm providing some additional information which is covering things not mentioned by his answer.

Comment: Just curious, why not just move to SparkSQL (instead of Hive/Pig), if we're already using Spark & want SQL capabilities?